# How can I shrink my clothes?

Tags: clothing

I have some shirts that are too big for me. I know that putting them in the dryer would shrink it but I did that and was not enough.

Is there any other (effective) way to make them smaller?

Comment: @diiN_ If you have an answer, please post it as one. If you have multiple answers, you can post multiple answers. See the [lifehacks manifesto](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2431/a-lifehacks-manifesto)

Comment: @diiN_ If you have an answer, please post it below. But please know that a link-only answer sending users elsewhere to find that information is not considered an answer and is not allowed on this site.

Comment: shrinking clothes is a bit of an urban myth, it depends on material, wash temperatures and as some will have noticed, directly after a wash some cotton clothing may shrink a bit, but once you've worn them for a bit expand and stretch. If you want an item of clothing properly resized take the tailor option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Washing in Hot water and/or drying on High Heat setting usually works. Although, I am sure this depends on the type of fabric you are attempting to shrink. I know it works on cotton shirts and denim jeans. Careful because it may ruin some fabrics.

Comment: Apart from the tiny caveat that shrinkage *may* be different for width and length, depending on the fabric.

Answer (score 2):

Effective WAY ::

Go to This Guy :

[image]

Comment: In what way is that a lifehack?

Comment: @Chenmunka -"You can't always know if a problem needs a life hack before you ask it. So if it turns out that someone's problem also has a "practical" solution, someone should be able to say so." From [the lifehacks manifesto](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2431/a-lifehacks-manifesto). Just because the answer isn't a lifehack, that doesn't mean that it's a bad answer.

Comment: Going to a tailor is a valid answer - it's a good idea if the clothing has significant value (like an expensive dress or suit). My wife paid $40 to have a $300 designer dress altered to fit her after a friend gave it to her.